# How to handle Fatal Error in Tesseract OCR 4.0 iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am using Tesseract OCR in my app. For gallery images it's working fine if I use a very clear image such as this one
[5 text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCbCx.png)

But for some images it gives me an error and the app crashes in my iPhone. App almost always crashes when I use a camera image as well. Now I want to know how to handle FATAL Error in Swift 2.2 . How can I show an alert that image was unreadable instead of crashing my app. I tried do {} catch {} but it doesn't work.

```
 func checkWithOCR() throws{

    let ocrSample = myImageView.image //image picker from gallery

    //FATAL ERROR ON THIS LINE.  
    tesseract.image = ocrSample!.fixOrientation().g8_blackAndWhite() 
        if(tesseract.recognize()){
            let recognizedText = tesseract.recognizedText
            if recognizedText != nil{
                print("recognizedText: \(recognizedText)")

                let trimmedText = String(recognizedText.characters.filter { !" \n\t\r,".characters.contains($0) })
                myImageView.image = tesseract.image
                convertCurrency(Float(trimmedText)!) //convert the tesseract text
            }
        }

    SwiftSpinner.hide()
}
```

HERE IS THE ERROR: 
recognizedText: 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I know why this error occurs as there was no value on the line I mentioned above. How can I show an alert box if this error occurs instead of a crash.

```
P.S: I tried if ( ocrSample!.fixOrientation().g8_blackAndWhite() != nil ) {}
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image` on a `UIImageView` is an `UIImage` optional, meaning that it can have a value (contain an image) or it can be `nil`.

So, when you're saying:

```
let ocrSample = myImageView.image
```

your `ocrSample` is now an `UIImage` optional, which you then have to unwrap before you use it.

When you then say:

```
tesseract.image = ocrSample!.fixOrientation().g8_blackAndWhite()
```

you are force unwrapping your `ocrSample` by using `!`, meaning that you are telling the compiler to just unwrap and use the optional, regardless of it being `nil` or not. This causes a crash when you then try to use that unwrapped optional if it contains `nil`.

What you can do is unwrap `ocrSample` using an `if let` like so:

```
func checkWithOCR() throws{

    if let ocrSample = myImageView.image {
        tesseract.image = ocrSample.fixOrientation().g8_blackAndWhite() 
        if(tesseract.recognize()){
            let recognizedText = tesseract.recognizedText
            if recognizedText != nil{
                print("recognizedText: \(recognizedText)")

                let trimmedText = String(recognizedText.characters.filter { !" \n\t\r,".characters.contains($0) })
                myImageView.image = tesseract.image
                convertCurrency(Float(trimmedText)!) //convert the tesseract text
            }
        }
        SwiftSpinner.hide()
    } else {
        //No value could be found, do your error handling here
    }
}
```

Here:

```
if let ocrSample = myImageView.image
```

you are trying to unwrap the value of `myImageView.image` into `ocrSample`, if that succeeds, then you know for sure that `ocrSample` is not `nil` and can use it onwards. If it fails, then you can do your error handling, show an alert view and whatever else you need to do.

Hope that helps you.